# channel_layer.group_send not working properly

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm going along with the channels documentation's tutorial and I have the exact same code as mentioned in the documentation's tutorial.
It's a simple chat application which echos the message to other connection in the same room.
here is my consumer class:

```
# chat/consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

the problem is the consumer is sending all messages only to the last connection of the same group. for example if i open 2 browser tabs with `/chat/room1/`, only the second tab will be able to see the messages.